# react native sqlite storage load custom extensions

Tags: android, react-native, android-sqlite

I have created an extension for `sqlite` database that i want to use in my react native app.

where should i place it in android directory and what is the path to it in the `sqlite` command?

i am using `react-native-sqlite-storage` and default `sqlite` storage

for example

`SELECT load_extension("path");`

i do not know the path to that extension

i have tried to use `asset` directory but it did not work